# passenger-install-nginx-module configuration

Tags: ubuntu, passenger, passenger-nginx

It seems like passenger-install-nginx-module will create an nginx binary in /opt/nginx and from there, starting/stopping it is a very manual process.

Is there a straightforward way to configure it for /etc/init.d/ or do I need to write those scripts manually?